# fitting data with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, regression, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have the following data:

```
>>> x
array([ 3.08,  3.1 ,  3.12,  3.14,  3.16,  3.18,  3.2 ,  3.22,  3.24,
    3.26,  3.28,  3.3 ,  3.32,  3.34,  3.36,  3.38,  3.4 ,  3.42,
    3.44,  3.46,  3.48,  3.5 ,  3.52,  3.54,  3.56,  3.58,  3.6 ,
    3.62,  3.64,  3.66,  3.68])

>>> y
array([ 0.000857,  0.001182,  0.001619,  0.002113,  0.002702,  0.003351,
    0.004062,  0.004754,  0.00546 ,  0.006183,  0.006816,  0.007362,
    0.007844,  0.008207,  0.008474,  0.008541,  0.008539,  0.008445,
    0.008251,  0.007974,  0.007608,  0.007193,  0.006752,  0.006269,
    0.005799,  0.005302,  0.004822,  0.004339,  0.00391 ,  0.003481,
    0.003095])
```

Now, I want to fit these data with, say, a 4 degree polynomial. So I do:

```
>>> coefs = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 4)
>>> ffit = np.poly1d(coefs)
```

Now I create a new grid for x values to evaluate the fitting function `ffit`:

```
>>> x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num=len(x)*10)
```

When I do all the plotting (data set and fitting curve) with the command:

```
>>> fig1 = plt.figure()                                                                                           
>>> ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)                                                                                   
>>> ax1.scatter(x, y, facecolors='None')                                                                     
>>> ax1.plot(x_new, ffit(x_new))                                                                     
>>> plt.show()
```

I get the following:

[image: fitting_data.png]
[fitting_data.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgr397vg2y1rfhh/fitdata.png)

What I expect is the fitting function to fit correctly (at least near the maximum value of the data). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Unfortunately, `np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` returns the coefficients in the opposite order of that for `np.polyfit` and `np.polyval` (or, as you used `np.poly1d`).  To illustrate:

```
In [40]: np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 4)
Out[40]: 
array([  84.29340848, -100.53595376,   44.83281408,   -8.85931101,
          0.65459882])

In [41]: np.polyfit(x, y, 4)
Out[41]: 
array([   0.65459882,   -8.859311  ,   44.83281407, -100.53595375,
         84.29340846])
```

In general: `np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` returns coefficients `[A, B, C]` to `A + Bx + Cx^2 + ...`, while `np.polyfit`  returns: `... + Ax^2 + Bx + C`.

So if you want to use this combination of functions, you must reverse the order of coefficients, as in:

```
ffit = np.polyval(coefs[::-1], x_new)
```

However, [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.html) states clearly to avoid `np.polyfit`, `np.polyval`, and `np.poly1d`, and instead to use only the new(er) package.

You're safest to use only the polynomial package:

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 4)
ffit = poly.polyval(x_new, coefs)
plt.plot(x_new, ffit)
```

Or, to create the polynomial function:

```
ffit = poly.Polynomial(coefs)    # instead of np.poly1d
plt.plot(x_new, ffit(x_new))
```

[image: fit and data plot]

Answer (score 38):

Note that you can use the Polynomial class directly to do the fitting and return a Polynomial instance.

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

p = Polynomial.fit(x, y, 4)
plt.plot(*p.linspace())
```

`p` uses scaled and shifted x values for numerical stability. If you need the usual form of the coefficients, you will need to follow with

```
pnormal = p.convert(domain=(-1, 1))
```

Comment: +1 for the conversion of coefficients, which is useful if you need to do some computation with other polynomials on the default domain. Note that this can be done in the `fit()` method directly, with the same `domain` argument.

Comment: The need for `convert()` can also be avoided by using the value `[]` for the `domain` argument (as of version 1.5).

Comment: To get the unscaled and unshifted coefficients, one can also do `p.convert().coef`

Answer (score 2):

### Fitting data with a Chebyshev Series and Polynomial Series least squares best fit curve using numpy and matplotlib

##### Quick summary

The key lines you need to pay attention to (in the full code below) which perform the data fitting are, for example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

# ...

cheby_series = Chebyshev.fit(x, y, deg=5)
x_cheby, y_cheby = cheby_series.linspace()

poly_series = Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg=5)
x_poly, y_poly = poly_series.linspace()

# ...

plt.plot(x_cheby, y_cheby, linewidth=6, alpha=0.5,
   label="Chebyshev Series 5th degree\nleast squares best fit curve")
plt.plot(x_poly, y_poly, 'k', linewidth=1,
   label="Polynomial Series 5th degree\nleast squares best fit curve")
```

---

Here's the output from my full program **below** (*not* from just the partial program snippet above):

[image]

##### Details

Even after reading all of the answers here, due to the changes in Matplotlib, and some other questions I had, I was really struggling with this until I finally found this demo!: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html.

It contains a great example at the very bottom, under the "Fitting" section!:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev as T

np.random.seed(11)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=.1, size=x.shape)
p = T.fit(x, y, 5)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
xx, yy = p.linspace()
plt.plot(xx, yy, lw=2)
p.domain
p.window
plt.show()
```

Here is an enhanced version of it, with my modifications and some helpful comments. I modified my code below from my [plot_best_fit_polynomial.py](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/matplotlib/plot_best_fit_polynomial.py) demo in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

# data to fit
x =   [0.        , 0.33069396, 0.66138793, 0.99208189, 1.32277585,
       1.65346982, 1.98416378, 2.31485774, 2.64555171, 2.97624567,
       3.30693964, 3.6376336 , 3.96832756, 4.29902153, 4.62971549,
       4.96040945, 5.29110342, 5.62179738, 5.95249134, 6.28318531]
y =   [ 0.17494547,  0.29609217,  0.5657562 ,  0.57183462,  0.9685718 ,
        0.96462136,  0.86211039,  0.76726418,  0.51805246,  0.05803429,
       -0.25321856, -0.52352074, -0.66675568, -0.85965411, -1.12713934,
       -1.08134779, -0.76348274, -0.45674931, -0.32780698, -0.06834466]

# Obtain a 5th degree (order) least-squares fit curve to the x, y data using a
# Chebyshev Series
cheby_series = Chebyshev.fit(x, y, deg=5)
# Lines-space: get evenly-spaced points to plot a line; see:
# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev.linspace.html
x_cheby, y_cheby = cheby_series.linspace()

# Now do the same things with a 5th order Polynomial Series fit as well!
# see: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html
poly_series = Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg=5)
x_poly, y_poly = poly_series.linspace()

# plot all the data

f1 = plt.figure()

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x_cheby, y_cheby, linewidth=6, alpha=0.5,
   label="Chebyshev Series 5th degree\nleast squares best fit curve")
plt.plot(x_poly, y_poly, 'k', linewidth=1,
   label="Polynomial Series 5th degree\nleast squares best fit curve")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

### Related:

1. I just figured out how to label plots too: [How to add a figure title, figure subtitle, figure footer, plot title, axis labels, legend label, and (x, y) point labels in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76311048/4561887)

### References:

1. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html - see demo at very bottom
2. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html#documentation-for-the-polynomial-package
3. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.chebyshev.html
4. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev.linspace.html
5. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html

Comment: Your first example graph doesn't represent the code: the code does a 5th degree polynomial fit whereas the graph says it is a chebyshev fit which is incorrect.

Comment: @user115625, I can see the confusion. I've updated my answer for clarity. I now say, "Here's the output from my full program **below** (_not_ from just the partial program snippet above)". Part of the goal of the `Quick summary` section was to orient you to where to look in the full code in the `Details` section.

Comment: And the full code in the `Details` section is what produced that plot.