# What are the weight values to use in numpy polyfit and what is the error of the fit

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, curve-fitting

I'm trying to do a linear fit to some data in numpy.

Ex (where w is the number of samples I have for that value, i.e. for the point `(x=0, y=0)` I only have 1 measurement and the value of that measurement is `2.2`, but for the point `(1,1)` I have 2 measurements with a value of `3.5`.

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([2.2, 3.5, 4.6, 5.2])
w = np.array([1, 2, 2, 1])

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, w = w)
```

So, now the question is:
is it correct to use `w=w` in polyfit for these cases or should I use `w = sqrt(w)` of what should I use?

Also, how can I get the fit error from polyfit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have normally distributed measurements, then your uncertainty in each value would be proportional to `1/sqrt(n)` where `n` is the number of measurements.  You want to weigh your fit by the inverse of your uncertainty, so your second guess is best:  `w=np.sqrt(n)`

To get the covariance on your parameters, also give `cov=True`.

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([2.2, 3.5, 4.6, 5.2])
n = np.array([1, 2, 2, 1])

p, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, w=np.sqrt(n), cov=True)
```

The diagonals of your `cov` matrix are the individual variances on each parameter, and of course the off-diagonals are the covariances.  So most likely what you want for "fit error" is the square root of these diagonals:

```
e = np.sqrt(np.diag(c))
```

Comment: Happy to help, @jbssm.  By the way, when using `np.polyfit`,`np.polyval`, `np.poly1d`, etc., don't combine them with any of the `np.polynomial` module functions, as they [follow different conventions, specifically the return ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767992/1730674).  Normally it's recommended to use the [`np.polynomial` package](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) exclusively, but for some reason [it doesn't provide the `covariance`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html)