# Multipolyfit (Python): What order are the coefficients in?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the function Multipolyfit to create a 2nd degree function with 3 independent variables ([trivariate quadratic](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/27b2570145a686a65d4317f8e7e58c95213a7e39)). The code is the following

```
data=numpy.loadtxt("file.txt")
hour=data[:,3]
day=data[:,4]
temp=data[:,5]
load=data[:,6]
a=multipolyfit.multipolyfit(numpy.vstack((hour,day,temp)).T, load, 2)
print a
```

Day, temp, and load are the independent variables. Load is the variable I am trying to predict.
The output seems to be the list of the 8 coefficients for my trivariate quadratic.

```
[ 27011.    771.   5462.   -394.    -29.    -83.     10.   -804.      9.      1]
```

What order are the above coefficients in?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767523/fitting-data-with-numpy

Comment: That is for one dependent variable. I am looking for multi-variable non-linear regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipolyfit is poorly documented. The author even mentions the following in their github readme file:

> I rarely respond to questions about this repository. It is oddly popular but the implementation is pretty dense and so this project generates a large number of reasonable questions. Unfortunately I don't have time to respond to all of these.
>
> I would care more about this project if it contained a useful algorithm. It doesn't.

Luckily for us, the code in its entirety is less than a hundred lines and pretty easy to navigate through. It creates permutations of the coefficient powers as:

```
[[2 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 2 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 2]]
```

where the columns correspond to the power of [1,hour,day,temp], respectively. So for your coefficients, you get `27011*(1**2) + 771*(1**1 * hour**1) + ...`. You can get this yourself without digging through the code by setting the keyword argument `powers_out=True`:

```
>>> a,powers=multipolyfit.multipolyfit(numpy.vstack((hour,day,temp)).T,
                                       load, 2, powers_out=True)
[array([2, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 1, 0]), array([1, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 2, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 1, 0]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 2, 0]), array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 2])]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I think the author of the library has the wrong definition of useful.