# Python, model a function based on x and y values

Tags: python, function, math, interpolation

I have a problem, I have 2 lists with x and y values, and I would like to create a function based on these. But the problem is that I would like to build a function like this one:

f(x) = a * (x-b)**c

I already know scipy.interpolate but I couldn't find anything to return a function like this one.

is there a quite easy way to try to create the best function I can by searching which values of a,b and c match the most?

thanks for your help!

Edit:

here is what my current values of x and y look like:

[image]

I created this function :

```
def problem(values):
    s = sum((y - values[0]*(x-values[1])**values[2])**2 for x,y in zip(X,Y))
    return(s)
```

and I tried to find the best values of a,b and c with scipy.optimize.minimize but I don't know with which values of a,b and c I should start...

```
values = minimize(problem,(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Is your question really about curve-fitting, that is choosing a, b & c to best fit some data?

Comment: You could use polyfit
Here is the link to a post you could use
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767523/fitting-data-with-numpy

Answer (score 2):

(Edited to account for the OP's added code and sub-question.)

The general idea is to use a least-squares minimization to find the "best" values of `a`, `b`, and `c`. First define a function whose parameters are `a, b, c` that returns the sum of the squares of the differences between the given `y` values and the calculated values of `a * (x-b)**c`. (That function can be done as a one-liner.) Then use an optimization routine, such as one found in scipy, to minimize the value of that function value. Those values of `a, b, c` are what you want--use them to define your desired function.

There are a few details to examine, such as restrictions on the allowed values of `a, b, c`, but those depend somewhat on your lists of `x` and `y` values.

Now that you have shown a graph of your `x` and `y` values, I see that your values are all positive and the function is generally increasing. For that common situation I would use the initial values

```
a = 1.0
b = 0.0
c = 1.0
```

That gives a straight line through the origin, in fact the line `y = x`, which is often a decent first guess. In your case the `x` and `y` values have a very different scale, with `y` about a hundred times larger than `x`, so you would probably get better results with changing the value of `a`:

```
a = 100.0
b = 0.0
c = 1.0
```

I can see even better values and some restrictions on the end values but I would prefer to keep this answer more general and useful for other similar problems.

Your function `problem()` looks correct to me, though I would have written it a little differently for better clarity. Be sure to test it.

Answer (score 0):

def problem (a , b, c, d):

return a * (x[d]-b)**c

I guess is what you are after. With D being what value of the X array. Not sure where Y comes into it.