# What's the difference between title() and suptitle()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created 3 subplots using `subplot()`. Now I'd like to add titles for each subplot. Which one of `title()` and `suptitle()` shall I use?

In general, what is the difference between them?

Comment: I think `title` applies to a specific axis within the figure, whereas `suptitle` applies to the whole figure (and all axes within it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the main figure title with `fig.suptitle` and subplot's titles with `ax.set_title` or by passing `title` to `fig.add_subplot`. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.01)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Main figure title')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311, title='Subplot 1 title')
ax1.plot(x, np.sin(x))

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax2.set_title('Subplot 2 title')
ax2.plot(x, np.cos(x))

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax3.set_title('Subplot 3 title')
ax3.plot(x, np.tan(x))

plt.show()
```

[image]

(You may need to manually tweak the font sizes to get the styling you want).
I think subtitles need special placement and sizing of the text. For example, see [Giving graphs a subtitle in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388450/giving-graphs-a-subtitle-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks for the concrete example. I misread `suptitle()` to `subtitle()`. Now it makes sense.

Comment: See also the methods [matplotlib.pyplot.title](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) and [matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html).

Comment: It looks like the "sup" in "suptitle" might stand for super.