# Multiple size font in suptitle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have multiple title in my graph. A picture is better than anyword :
[image]

I use a `title` for every graph (D2/E, D3/E and D4/E) and a `suptitle` for title 1 and 2 but they have the same font size. Is there a solution to have different size for Title 1 and Title 2 ?

I've already seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836048/python-matplotlib-multiple-font-sizes-in-one-label?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) using LaTeX but the thing is when I use `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` every font and text are changed. Moreover, I use variable in each title and it looks like I can't do it with LaTeX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) objects in order to achieve the same result. Note that you need to make sure you use the figure coordinate system by using the `transform=fig.transFigure` argument and set the horizontal alignment using `ha = "center"`

An example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)
plt.text(x=0.5, y=0.94, s="My title 1", fontsize=18, ha="center", transform=fig.transFigure)
plt.text(x=0.5, y=0.88, s= "My title 2 in different size", fontsize=12, ha="center", transform=fig.transFigure)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.set_title("D{}/E".format(i))

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8, wspace=0.3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution but without using 'transform=fig.transFigure', it wasn't working well, thanks a lot!