# Inconsistent alignment of title and suptitle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use both `ax.set_title()` and `plt.suptitle()` to incorporate a title and a subtitle to a graph, but the two seem to not share the same alignment. For example, the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cats = ('One', 'Two')
vals = (12, 4) 

ax.barh(cats, vals, align='center')
plt.suptitle('Title')
ax.set_title('Title')
plt.show()
```

Gives us the following misaligned titles:

[image: Misaligned titles with short y labels]

How can I get these two titles to align properly? I thought it may be something to do with `ax.title` aligning to the axis and `plt.suptitle` aligning to the figure, but testing a much longer y label doesn't seem to affect the offset:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cats = ('One million tiny engines running at one hundred miles per hour', 'Two')
vals = (12, 4) 

ax.barh(cats, vals, align='center')
plt.suptitle('Title')
ax.set_title('Title')
plt.show()
```

[image: Misaligned titles with long y label]

Comment: Could it be a bug, where the position is calculated using two different methods, which consistently produce a slight offset? Otherwise, there's this option:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388450/giving-graphs-a-subtitle-in-matplotlib. It's not very clean though.

Comment: Suptitle is usually imagined as a title that is above many subplots, not a single subplot, so as noted below, it is centred on the figure, not the axes.  

If you want a 2-line title, you can just do `ax.set_title('First Line\nSecond Line')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

matplotlib aligns suptitle to the *figure*, and title to the *subplot*. You can manually jiggle the suptitle using `fig.subplotpars`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cats = ('One', 'Two')
vals = (12, 4) 

# Mid point of left and right x-positions
mid = (fig.subplotpars.right + fig.subplotpars.left)/2

ax.barh(cats, vals, align='center')
plt.suptitle('Title',x=mid)
ax.set_title('Title')
plt.show()
```

[image: Fixed title]

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, this is ideal. I've added in an image of the fixed graph to make the correction clearer to anyone who finds this answer in future. Also, welcome to SO! Looks like you're making a great start to me.

Comment: With tight layout, you need to do it twice: before tight_layout() -- to reserve some vertical space; and after -- to actually align it horizontally, because x coordinates will change

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't the perfect answer and basically a repost of my comment, but here goes nothing:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cats = ('hour', 'Two')
vals = (12, 4) 
ax.barh(cats, vals, align='center')
plt.figtext(.5,.95,'Foo Bar', fontsize=18, ha='center')
plt.figtext(.5,.9,'lol bottom text',fontsize=10,ha='center')
plt.show()
```

You need to manually adjust the .95 and .9 values depending on the font sizes though.

Comment: This is definitely an interesting way to do it, and would be useful for other alignments of the text, but @soyapencil's answer is more suitable in my situation I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't need `subtitle`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cats = ('One million tiny engines running at one hundred miles per hour', 'Two')
vals = (12, 4) 

ax.barh(cats, vals, align='center')
ax.set_title('Title\nTitle')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've given a simplified version here - in my case I *do* need `suptitle`